# CSOM code deployment in SharePoint On premise as well as SharePoint Online

Tags: csom

I am new to SharePoint Client Object model. It will be very thankful if someone outlines the steps required to deploy  CSOM code in SharePoint on premise as well as SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

In **SharePoint 2013 On-premise**,

- You can deploy your WSP to SharePoint farm

  1. Run the below command on **SharePoint 2013 Management Shell**.

  `Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "path to wsp file\EventReceiverProject.wsp"`

  example : `Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "C:\EventReceiverProject.wsp"`

  2. On the Central Administration Home page, click **System Settings**.
  3. In the Farm Management section, click **Manage farm solutions**.
  4. On the Solution Management page, click the solution that you want to deploy.
  5. On the Solution Properties page, click **Deploy Solution**.
  6. On the Deploy Solution page, in the Deploy When section, select one of the following:

     a. **Now**

     b. **At a specified time**. If you select this option, specify a time by using the date and time boxes. We recommend that you select a time when the load on the destination servers is low.
  7. In the **Deploy To?** Section, in the **A specific web application list**, click either **All web applications** or select a specific Web application.
  8. Click **OK**.
  9. Now open your site, go to **Site Settings** -> **Site features**
  10. Activate the feature if it is not active.

---

In **SharePoint Online**, you can deploy your wsp (**No Code WSP**) because Microsoft has restricted managed code.

Reference:

- [Deprecation of Custom Code in Sandboxed Solutions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions/)
- http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2016/08/sandbox-code-disabled-in-Office-365.html

You can create **SharePoint hosted** / **Provider hosted** app or **pure client-side development**.

Reference:

a. [Get started creating SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx)

b. [Step by Step approach to create a Provider Hosted Application in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-approach-to-create-a-Provider-Hosted-Application-in-SharePoint-2013)

You can use **Content Editor** / **Script Editor**  web parts and place **JavaScript**, **REST API** code with HTML design in the web parts or You can attach JS files to that web parts and place files in Style Library.